# Can I load balance logstash cluster with nginx

Tags: nginx, logstash, filebeat

I have 2 logstash servers that listen on 5000 from multiple filebeats. Only one of the logstash servers is getting traffic. Can I loadbalance these with nginx? Can I do the same with a cluster of elasticsearch servers?

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't sound like an issue.

I might suggest using haproxy as the reverse proxy in both cases though.  Nginx has a good rep for serving data fast, but not as good with reverse proxy out of the box - lots of 504 gateway timeout issues and minimal metrics compared to haproxy.

You could configure the same proxy to be used for the logstash and elasticsearch server group.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. I had a version of nginx that was built without the --with-stream tags that allow me to proxy tcp traffic. works now.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem doing load-balancing using NginX for the Logstash. Just be aware that you need to use `stream` block instead of `http` to do load-balancing in tcp/udp layer. That's because filebeat uses a protocol called *lumberjack* to connect logstash server. This protocol sits on the top of tcp. So, your NginX configuration should look like this:

```
stream {
    upstream logstash {
        server logstash-1:5044;
        server logstash-2:5044;
    }

    server {
        listen        5044;
        listen   [::]:5044;

        proxy_pass logstash;
    }
}
```

Here I used docker to run `logstash-1` and `logstash-2` on separate containers so they can be on the same 5044 port. Feel free to change these addresses based on your specific logstash hosts and ports.